# Invalid cast exception - Unable to cast object type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
public void ConstructUpdateableInventoryItemsOnThisPage(DataView dv)
{
    //DataRowView dv = null;
    string sTemp = "";

    foreach (DataRow dr in dv)
    {
        if (sTemp.Length > 0)
        {
            sTemp += ",";
            sTemp += dr["inventory_id"];
        }
    }

    //foreach (DataRow dr in dv)
    //{
    //    if (sTemp.Length > 0)
    //        sTemp += ",";
    //    sTemp += dr.ItemArray[Convert.ToInt32("inventory_id")];  //added ItemArray keyword, square brackets and syntax to convert from string to int 10/21/15 Max //

    //}



    mUpdateableInventoryItemsOnThisPage = sTemp;

}
```

And when I go to execute the code I receive the following error:

> Invalid Cast Exception
>       - Unable to cast object type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

I know that the issue is somewhere in the `foreach` statement so just in case I included the original code (commented out) and the changes that I made (not commented out).  I am not sure what is causing this could someone point me in the right direction syntactically

Oh by the way this was converted from visual basic if that helps any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
foreach(DataRowView dr in dv)
```

and that should fix the issue, The items in the `DataView` are `DataRowView` and not `DataRow`, and **since `foreach` does a silent explicit conversion**, you don't see an error at compile time. (More [here](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/))

You can also get the required string using `String.Join` like:

```
sTemp = String.Join(",", 
                dv.OfType<DataRowView>().Select(dr => 
                                                Convert.ToString(dr["inventory_id"])));
```

if you want to have `,` in front of your string then you can use concatenation before `string.Join`

Answer (score 0):

The `DataRowView` is not convertible to `DataRow`. You can use `DataRowView` instead of `DataRow` in `foreach`. Like this:

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in dv)
{
     if (sTemp.Length > 0)
     {
          sTemp += ",";
          sTemp += dr.Row["inventory_id"];
     }
}
```

Or as a better solution by LINQ:

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in dv.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(dr => sTemp.Length > 0))
{
    sTemp += ",";
    sTemp += dr.Row["inventory_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataView isn't an enumerable of type DataRow. It's not an array or list of rows. It has a single row accessible with the Row property dv.Row.

You can climb up the hierarchy and back down the the rows: dv.Table.Rows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx